# Disable "As low as" price in Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, price, product-grid

I am working on a **Magento 2.1.7** shop.

On my category pages, I need to disable "As low as" price, as it ruins the products *grid*.

[image]

I want to hide it on configurable and non-configurable products, but *only* on the *category pages*. If possible, **not** with CSS (`display: none`).

What is the easiest and/or the most appropriate way to do this?

Comment: do you want to show for configurable product?

Comment: I would prefer to hide it on _any_ kind of product, but only on the category page.

Comment: magento 2 default showing only for bundle, is your product is bundle product?

Comment: I have added details to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved it with a piece of less/css:

```
.product-items .minimal-price-link {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: How can this be removed from the product page as well?

Answer (score 0):

check below code:-

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

?>

<?php
$idSuffix = $block->getIdSuffix() ? $block->getIdSuffix() : '';
/** @var \Magento\Bundle\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $block */

/** @var \Magento\Bundle\Pricing\Price\FinalPrice $finalPriceModel */
$finalPriceModel = $block->getPrice();
$minimalPrice = $finalPriceModel->getMinimalPrice();
$maximalPrice = $finalPriceModel->getMaximalPrice();
/** ex: \Magento\Bundle\Pricing\Price\BundleRegularPrice */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Price\PriceInterface $regularPriceModel */
$regularPriceModel = $block->getPriceType('regular_price');
$maximalRegularPrice = $regularPriceModel->getMaximalPrice();
$minimalRegularPrice = $regularPriceModel->getMinimalPrice();
?>


<?php if ($block->getSaleableItem()->getPriceView()): ?>
    <p class="minimal-price">
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($minimalPrice, [
            'display_label'     => __('As low as'),
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('from-'),
            'include_container' => true
        ]); ?>
        <?php if ($minimalPrice < $minimalRegularPrice): ?>
            <span class="old-price">
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($minimalRegularPrice, [
                    'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
                    'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
                    'include_container' => true,
                    'skip_adjustments'  => true
                ]); ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif ?>
    </p>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php if ($block->showRangePrice() && !$block->isProductList()): ?>
        <p class="price-from">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($minimalPrice, [
                'display_label'     => __('From'),
                'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('from-'),
                'price_type'        => 'minPrice',
                'include_container' => true
            ]); ?>
            <?php if ($minimalPrice < $minimalRegularPrice): ?>
                <span class="old-price">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($minimalRegularPrice, [
                        'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
                        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
                        'include_container' => true,
                        'skip_adjustments'  => true
                    ]); ?>
                </span>
            <?php endif ?>
        </p>
        <p class="price-to">
            <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($maximalPrice, [
                'display_label'     => __('To'),
                'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('to-'),
                'price_type'        => 'maxPrice',
                'include_container' => true
            ]); ?>
            <?php if ($maximalPrice < $maximalRegularPrice): ?>
                <span class="old-price">
                    <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($maximalRegularPrice, [
                        'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
                        'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
                        'include_container' => true,
                        'skip_adjustments'  => true
                    ]); ?>
                </span>
            <?php endif ?>
        </p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($minimalPrice, [
            'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('product-price-'),
            'include_container' => true
        ]); ?>
        <?php if ($minimalPrice < $minimalRegularPrice): ?>
            <span class="old-price">
                <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->renderAmount($minimalRegularPrice, [
                    'display_label'     => __('Regular Price'),
                    'price_id'          => $block->getPriceId('old-price-' . $idSuffix),
                    'include_container' => true,
                    'skip_adjustments'  => true
                ]); ?>
            </span>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Your code shows `<?php if ($block->getSaleableItem()->getPriceView()): ?>` _twice_. I only have it once.

Comment: I'm afraid It does not work.

Comment: is there showing any error

Comment: No, so maybe this is wrong: `$block->isProductList()`...

Comment: There is an `11` before the first if statement.

Comment: removed please check

Comment: "As low as" and the price are still there...

Comment: i already test code in my envrionment, make sure you are editing right file, flush the cache and varnish if enable

Comment: File path: `vendor/magento/module-bundle/view/base/templates/product/price/final_price.phtml`

Answer (score -1):

We are looking for the following line in the translation file (En_en, Fr_fr... etc.)

**"As low as","As low as"**
change to
**"As low as",""**